# can't see hosted website

Tags: hosting

I cant get access to website hosted by my PC.
when I type my ip for ex 83.12.12.123/website.html I get error

> Object Not Found
>   The requested URL '/website.html' was not found on the RomPager server.
>   Return to last page

but when somebody else try to connect this address from another IP everything is fine:(

I am using WampServer Version 2.2
and my router is Edimax ar-7064gA

any ideas?

PS.this is my 1st time hosting app i am completely green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address 83.12.12.123 will be for your PC as seen from outside the firewall created by your Edimax ASDL router. Inside the firewall your PCs address will be different.

As you're on Windows, try `systeminfo` (reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491007.aspx) at a command prompt to find your current IP address.

Also, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621728/cant-browse-a-website-hosted-at-home-on-local-machine for related issues and fixes that may permit you to use the outside IP address.

(Note, this isn't really a StackOverflow question as this site is mostly for specific programming issues.)